# Adding a custom extension to executable made with makefile

Tags: makefile

I have this very basic makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O -pedantic -Wformat=2 -Wextra -lm
```

And actually it compile `foo.c` to `foo.` How can I add a custom extension, for example I want it to compile `foo.c` in `foo.run`.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `makefile`:

```
foo.run : foo.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Make sure the second line starts with a tab character, not spaces. Then check out the manual page or other documentation for your version of make.

Comment: In this way, only foo.c is built in foo.run, while I want every c source file built in *.run (where * is the name of the source file).

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov - that's definitely the right way to go since the OP has multiple targets to build - the original question didn't make that clear. If there's only one target to be built that way, I prefer explicitly stating it the way I did, to avoid future surprises.